# left inverse == right inverse with Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

1) No matter how the pseudoinverse is constructed, it is always the same? No matter if i use QR or SVD

2) Is the left inverse and the right inverse the same in Moore-Penrose pseudoinverses?

Comment: There are in general many left-, right- and pseudoinverses, Moore-Penrose is just a particular construction with en extra nice property.

Comment: Yes, thats how i understood the generalized pseudoinverse. Thats why my question aims not for the general answer, but for the moore-penrose answer only...

Comment: What forms does the Moore-Penrose inverse take under systems with full rank, full column rank, and full row rank? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/moore-penrose-inverse-solves-the-least-square-solution#1537880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As M.-P. pseudoinverse is defined, it is *unique* for real/complex matrices, i.e. does not depend on the way you calculate it.
2. If a matrix is not square, it may be invertible at most from one side, i. e. a left and a right inverses cannot exist for a non-square matrix simultaneously. If the matrix is square and has a left and a right inverse, then they are equal
   $$
   A^{-L}=A^{-L}(AA^{-R})=(A^{-L}A)A^{-R}=A^{-R}.
   $$
   Moreover, the one side invertible square matrix must be necessarily invertible. For example, for left invertible we have
   $$
   n=\text{rank}\, I=\text{rank}\,A^{-L}A\le\text{rank}\, A\le n\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{rank}\,A=n
   $$
   and the left inverse, the right inverse, the M.-P. pseudoinverse and the normal inverse are the same.